# react mobx, component does not render new observable

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I am using Mobx with React (typescript) to get some data from firebase and display it. at the first render no data is rendered on the screen till I change for instance tabs in view that the component get re-rendered.

- the component class:

  ```
  interface Props {id: string; mytore?: MyStore;}
  @inject('mystore')
  @observer
  export class myClass extends Component<Props>{
    constructor(props: Props) {super(props);}
    componentDidMount() {   this.props.mystore!.getBs(this.props.id);}
    render() {
       const { arrB } = this.props.mystore!;
       return (
          <div>{arrB.map((e) => (<h3 key={`${e.id}`}>{e.name}</h3>))}</div>
          );
       }
  }
  ```
- the store class

  ```
  export class MyStore{
  @observable arrA=[];
  @observable arrB=[];

  constructor(){this.loadAllAs()}

  @action.bound loadAllAs(){runInAction(async()=>(this.arrA=await /*fetchfunction*/))}

  @action getBs(id){this.arrB=arrA.filter(/*some logic*/)}
  }
  ```

  so here the `arrB` gets manipulated after calling the method, and it is an observable which get destructures at render method of the component so I was expecting any changes to the `arrB` result in a re-render but nothing happens till regarding other actions `componentDidMount` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Because arrB must be @computed
[computed](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html)

```js
@computed
getBs(id){
   return this.arrA.filter(/*some logic*/)}
}

const { getBs } = this.props.mystore!;

getBs(id).map...
```